# CUDA warp / block finalization

Tags: cuda, gpu-warp

When a warp finishes a kernel, but another warp of the same block is still running, will the finished warp be blocked until the other warps of the same block finish, or will the finished warp be available for immediate reuse by another block while the other warps of the current block are still running?

Answer (score 4):

A finished warp is retired, freeing up the warp slot in the scheduler queue for another warp, whether from the same block or another one.  The number of warps that can be open at any time and ready for execution by the warp scheduler is limited based on the specific hardware type (compute capability).  The number of threadblocks that can be open (scheduled) at any given time on a SM is also limited by compute capability.  Therefore, if all the warps but one of a particular block are finished and retired, but one warp is still active, then that warp uses up a warp slot, and the block that it belongs to also uses up a block slot.    Only when all the warps of a block are finished and retired does the block get retired, freeing it's block slot for use by another block.

Comment: Thanks, that explains, why the technique of persistent threads is useful for raytracing applications, where the thread divergence may be significant and some threads may finish much later than the others. Without thread persistance, some blocks may become nearly idle for significant part of the total time.